# How to repaint only dirty region in Swing?

Tags: java, swing

1. Does repainting dirty region only improve performance?
2. If the answer is yes, how to do it?
   Originally I use repaint() to call paintComponent(Graphics); however, recently I aware that repaint() is actually repaint(0,0,width,height), which repaints everything each time. If I use repaint() with parameters to specify the dirty region, in what way will it pass such data to paintComponent(Graphics)?

Comment: *"Does repainting dirty region only improve performance?"* not unless you code is optimised to work with it. Unless you're checking the current `clip` bounds AND only updating what appears in it, it offers little in the way of a performance improvement - because at the end of the day, Java still needs to paint the entire resulting bitmap to the screen - maybe have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) which has a discussion on the subject

Answer (score 3):

> If I use repaint() with parameters to specify the dirty region, in what way will it pass such data to paintComponent(Graphics)?

The "clip bounds" or the Graphics object will be set to the specified region

> 1.Does repainting dirty region only improve performance?

Why? Do you have a painting problem. Don't micro optimize the code, unless you have a reason to do so. The code will be harder to maintain and debug. You will be adding extra logic to determine which regions need to be repainted.

Also, remember that multiple repaint requests get merged into a single request. So if you make a request to repaint the top/left corner of a component and the immediately request a repaint of the bottom/right, these two request will be merged into an area that includes both regions, which means the entire component will be repainted. So you have done extra work for nothing.

Comment: I have a paint method that makes lots of calls to Graphics.fill(). Some shapes change when the mouse moves near them, so I was repainting everything naively. It lagged considerably at 4K size. I get much better performance with repaint(bounds). No need to reduce the number of calls to fill(). 

Answer (score 0):

To repaint only "dirty" regions of a large `JComponent` you will need to use the [`RepaintManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/RepaintManager.html).  You can get the current `RepaintManager` with:

```
RepaintManager rm = RepaintManager.currentManager(component);
```

You can even replace the `RepaintManager` with your own custom version.  Additional details can be found on [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)'s website.

Comment: You don't use the RepaintManager directly to paint dirty regions. Repaint requests are forwarded to the RepaintManager automatically by Swing every time you make a repaint(...) request on a component, The specified region is added as a dirty region. The RepaintManager will then consolidate these dirty regions for you and then invoke paint() on the component.